# Retrieve image from mysql-php(android)

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-imageview, android-bitmap

i have a image in image table field and i want to use that image in my app
my php page is

```
$user = array();
$user["image"] = base64_encode($result["image"]);
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// user node
$response["image_table"] = array();

array_push($response["image_table"], $user);
```

when i use that array in my app i use this...

```
if (success == 1)
{
    address = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE_TABLE);
    for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(i);
    image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

}
```

it gives me result like

```
json response: {"success":1,"image_table":     [{"image":"iVBORw0KGgoAAA...................."
```

when i use this image in my image view i use this like

```
ImageView ivProperty = ((ImageView) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.image_property));

byte[] decodedString;
try {
        decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.URL_SAFE);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        ivProperty.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
    } catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But It Gives Me null pointer exception

my logcat values are

```
03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):   java.lang.NullPointerException: Input string was null.
03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at com.big_property_info.Base64.decode(Base64.java:1242)
03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):     at  com.big_property_info.MainActivityMap$GeocoderTask$2.getInfoContents(MainActivityMap.java:314)
```

How to solve that null pointer exception ...when i m receiving image string.....

Comment: Help Me friend i need your help.......

Comment: `t gives me result like `. What are you printing there? Which result? At least put the log statement in your code so we can see what you are printing.

Comment: 03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391): java.lang.NullPointerException: Input string was null.
03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):  at com.big_property_info.Base64.decode(Base64.java:1242)
03-27 10:10:44.355: E/AndroidRuntime(2391):  at com.big_property_info.MainActivityMap$GeocoderTask$2.getInfoContents(MainActivityMap.java:314)

Comment: You had already posted that. Why are you posting that again? You did not understand my question. I quoted you. Look in your text for the origin of the quote. Then add the asked code in the post.

Comment: About your null pointer exception. Tell which pointer is null.

Comment: this is my bas64 class and it gives error here

Comment: public static byte[] decode( String s, int options ) throws java.io.IOException {
        
        if( s == null ){
            throw new NullPointerException( "Input string was null." );
        }   // end if

Comment: i receve null pointer exception here

Comment: No. There it is thrown. But where is it received?  I asked also what was null in your code. And react on my first comment please.

Comment: i want to display image in my image view

Comment: so i create a php page nd return decoded string

Comment: in json i m receiving this by a string variable image

Comment: nd use this variable on onother class which have my imageview

Comment: any one have the soln...then help me

Comment: If you want help you should answer the questions and comments you get. You did not do that. You chase people away answering the way you did.

Comment: sorry bro i will take care of it,..

Comment: It is possible that the `image` string is `null`. Did you posted the full code? Maybe you could be hiding some important parts. Try to debug your code.

Comment: image string is not null bro.....i had posted json response code...but i m use it in onother class...that class says me image string is null..if i  use a variable to initilize then nothing is displayed

Comment: Where did `image` come from -- I don't see the code that assigned it.  The JSON has "image" buried in an associative array buried in an array, not a variable.

Comment: 1. Parse your JSON response with JSON library create json object and print yoru base64 image string. If it print successfully then pass same to base64
2. Base64 is not good idea to download or upload image, because when you create base64 it will increase size 3x, Android app might go out of heap.

Comment: Why is MySQL tagged?

Comment: Does the Base64.decode() part run within the same if (success == 1) block?

Comment: Google introduce Volley library that is very helpful to you load the images

Answer (score 1):

You can use Picasso for load images easily. For example:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). Its image downloader library and easy to implement.

```
DisplayImageOptions imageOptions;
ImageLoader imageLoader; 

     imageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable
                    .logo_image).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.logo_image).cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .build();
            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));

imageLoader.displayImage(uri, imageView, imageOptions);
//Where uri is url of imageview stored in server. imageview is Imageview in which you want to show image.
```

Check out link for document in github.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your string whether it is null or not.

```
 ImageView ivProperty = ((ImageView) myContentView.findViewById(R.id.image_property));

    byte[] decodedString;
    try {   
if (image!=null&&!image.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
               decodedString = Base64.decode(image, Base64.URL_SAFE);
                  Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                  ivProperty.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is causing because of characterset which is used for encoding and decoding in php and android

Use same Characterset for both ends for Encoding and Decoding image data

refer this link to resolve your problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15156991/4985541

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting image in Base64 string you can decode it like this,

```
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```

Or you can get the link also from server and use below code to show it on image view.

```
if (imageUrl != null && isImageUrl) {
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Constants.IMG_URL + imageUrl).resize(150, 100).centerInside().into(ivActionHome);
}
```