# Server PHP script won't properly decode Base64 image string from Android Device

Tags: php, android, post, base64

I am trying to send text data and a Base64encoded image string to my test server. The data is sent in pairs.

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
            params .add(new BasicNameValuePair("ownName", text1));
            params .add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", text4));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", text2));
            params .add(new BasicNameValuePair("petName", text5));
            params .add(new BasicNameValuePair("zipCode", text3));
            params .add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", imageString));
```

The image is encoded into a string(where 'b' is my compressed bitmap) and sent to the server with the text items.

```
imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I add the text information to my database and I want to store the image on the server. I'm certain that my PHP script on my server is wrong. I have tried some of the suggestions from other posts with the same question, but I have not been successful. The image name shows up in the directory that I specify, but it is 0kb in size and cannot be opened. At the moment, I'm trying this type of format for my PHP side

```
$data = $_POST["image"]; 
list($type, $data) = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
file_put_contents('../image1.jpg', $data[1]);
```

I have tried many variations of this but none have worked. Am I parsing the right portion of the POST image? I appreciate any help/input.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156811/encoding-decoding-of-data-between-php-java-for-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it with this:

```
<?php

$base = $_POST["image"];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$file = fopen('uploaded_image1.jpg', 'w');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);

?>
```